# How can I resolve two foreign key and three table relation with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I can't resolve this relation with eloquent. I don't know, maybe it is illegal relation. But I can't think of another relationship. I need one `CustomerCodeReferences` row from `SaleProduct` row.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand this diagram. You are linking customer_id from documents with customer_id from CustomerCodeReferences. Wouldn't the more logical link be between each of these tables and the customers table?

Comment: Customers has many Documents, Documents has many SaleProduct and SaleProduct has one Product, this is the logic. I am trying do product can has many code by customer. This is the reason why exists CustomerCodeReferences. I need get the special customer code from SaleProduct model. I hope I could explain.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
class CustomerCodeReference extends Model
{
    public function saleProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\SaleProduct::class, 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Document::class, 'customer_id', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function scopeCustomer($query, int $customer)
    {
        $query->where('customer_id', $customer);
    }
}
```

```
class Document extends Model
{
    public function saleProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\SaleProduct::class);
    }

    public function customerCodeReferences()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\CustomerCodeReference::class, 'customer_id', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

```
class SaleProduct extends Model
{
    public function customerCodeReferences()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\CustomerCodeReference::class, 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }

    public function documents()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Document::class);
    }
}
```

The `Project`'s `CustomerCodeReference`s  can be accessed like this:

```
$project->customerCodeReference()->customer(1)->get();
```

Comment: This relations correct but I need one row customerCodeReference from SaleProduct model what it related the customer and product. Because what I am trying to do, every product has different code by customer.

Comment: I added a scope. Does that meet your requirements?

Comment: This scope need customer id, I need code reference for every SaleProduct row.